# (Angular 6) FullCalendar is not loading correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to make a small application to learn the operation of FullCalendar and then use it in a larger application.
So far so good.
I looked for several tutorials on how to integrate FullCalendar into Angular 6, and found this: "https://github.com/lbertenasco/ap-ng2-fullcalendar",
I followed all the steps, all the instructions and the calendar still did not load correctly.

I tried to import the JavaScript files manually, without success.
I did the same thing with CSS files, they even had some reaction, but not the one I wanted for the project to work right. I tried importing into style.css and also into the angular.json file. Nothing works.

**This is my "app.module.ts"**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarModule } from "ap-angular-fullcalendar";
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CalendarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**This is my app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarComponent } from 'ap-angular-fullcalendar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) myCalendar: CalendarComponent;

    changeCalendarView(view) {
      this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('changeView', view);
    }

    calendarOptions:Object = {
      height: 'parent',
      fixedWeekCount : false,
      defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: [
        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2016-09-01'
        },
        {
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: '2016-09-07',
          end: '2016-09-10'
        },
        {
          id: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2016-09-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          id: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2016-09-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Conference',
          start: '2016-09-11',
          end: '2016-09-13'
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2016-09-12T10:30:00',
          end: '2016-09-12T12:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Lunch',
          start: '2016-09-12T12:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2016-09-12T14:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Happy Hour',
          start: '2016-09-12T17:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Dinner',
          start: '2016-09-12T20:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Birthday Party',
          start: '2016-09-13T07:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Click for Google',
          url: 'http://google.com/',
          start: '2016-09-28'
        }
      ]
    };

    onCalendarInit(initialized: boolean) {
      console.log('Calendar initialized');
    }
}
```

**This is my app.component.html**

```
<angular2-fullcalendar [options]="calendarOptions" (initialized)="onCalendarInit($event)"></angular2-fullcalendar>
```

**This is my styles.css**

```
@import "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css";
```

I just want the calendar to appear the same way it was to appear.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: No, unfortunately no error is shown.

Comment: Try to recreate it here https://stackblitz.com/ if you can.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to reproduce the project.